# Show different content (layouts) depending on available width/height in Android Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, height, width, android-jetpack-compose

I have an `Activity` and `MyApp` composable function. In the function I need to show either list with details or just list screen depending on the available width. How to determine available width for the content I want to show using **Jetpack Compose**? What is a good practice for this using **Compose**?

```
class MyActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ProjectTheme {
                MyApp()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    val isLarge: Boolean = ...// how to determine whether the available width is large enough?
    if (isLarge) {
        ListScreenWithDetails()
    } else {
        ListScreen()
    }
}

@Composable
fun ProjectTheme(darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    // ... project theme
}
```

Comment: check out [Build adaptive layouts](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/adaptive)

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
```

Then:

```
val isLargeWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp > 840
```

Answer (score 0):

For a generic solution, consider using the Window Size Classes, see [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes#window_size_classes) and [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/windowsizeclass/package-summary#calculateWindowSizeClass(android.app.Activity)) for reference.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
        val windowSizeClass = calculateWindowSizeClass(this)
        MyApp(windowSizeClass)
    }
}
```